# Which language would be best suited to produce a multimedia player/manager?

Tags: java, php, c++, html, multimedia

I have a major project for my last year of high school and I am required to complete a software solution to create a multimedia player/manager in any operating system, but I have my preference set on Windows. Simply it requires the playback of many common media files, the display of metadata of these media files (ID3 tags etc.), management of the files as in adding files to the library and the ability to add notes to individual files. Also the grouping of different file types and the ability to search for specific file types or specific files.

I have knowledge in very simple `Python`, a basic knowledge of `Java` (like arrays, while loops, dabbling in some Swing), pretty decent knowledge in `HTML` and `PHP` with `MySQL` database interactivity. We had a project last year that involved creating a website that would essentially be an online store. It had user accounts, dynamic product pages (as the database updated, the page would), saving a wishlist to a text file etc.

So my question is what would be the best language for me to complete this? I have looked into using `Java` as I have some ability to use arrays and a GUI, but i understand that I'll need a library for multimedia playback. I've looked into `JMF`, `JSFML`, `JavaFx` and these libraries are either outdated or don't completely solve my needs. Although I am willing to try harder with Java. My other option that I thought about would be a `HTML` and `PHP` combination as I know `HTML` natively supports audio and video in `HTML5` and I also found [this website](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/) of a project which would help me greatly in getting meta data within a HTML and PHP situation. On the other hand I wanted to know if I could learn something like `C++` just for this project and if `C++` or any other language would be the easiest to learn for this?

Comment: On which operating system? Multimedia is operating system specific!

Comment: Edited it, but anyway I will use Windows.

Answer (score 2):

To build production quality and cross-platform code, I'd suggest to use C++/QT
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtmultimedia-index.html

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this. Would C++ be hard to learn for my purposes?

Comment: C++ is indeed not an easy language to learn, but you can feel this is a good opportunity to learn some of it.

Comment: Not really if you know java. Actually, it will take knowledge of QL library more rather than pure C++. But fortunately, there is a very nice tool to create Qt  apps - Qt Creator. I hope this will inspire you :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HrMSIrhFYlY

Comment: What is the basis of your recommendation?  Why do you not recommend other approaches?  Why is your recommendation "the best"? ... which is what the OP (unrealistically) asks for.

Comment: Dear Stephen, my recommendation is "the best" just because there is no any other here :) Please, fix it.